# Java EE NamedQuery and JOIN statement - results in EJB Exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, ejb, named-query

I have an entity called Lots as follows:

```
public class Lots implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int lotId;

@ManyToOne
private Boats boats;

private int numCrates;

....
```

And I also have an entity called Boats:

```
public class Boats implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int boatId;

@ManyToOne
private Users user;

private String name;
```

I am trying to create a named query on Lots as follows:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "FindUsersByLot", query = "SELECT b FROM Lots b JOIN Boats a ON     (b.boats.boatId = a.boatId) WHERE a.user = :user")    
})
```

But this results in an EJB Exception.

How can I do a JOIN in a named query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, when you're asking why you get an exception, please post the stacktrace. However, I think the problem is that you're still thinking `SQL` when you should be thinking `JPQL`. Try this instead:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "FindUsersByLot", query = "SELECT b FROM Lots b JOIN b.boats a WHERE a.user = :user")
```

Explanation - you're assuming that each `Lots` record will contain a `boatId` column, which may or may not be the case. In `@ManyToOne` the JPA provider will likely opt to storing the relationship on the `Boats` side. As for why did I write the query the way I did, look into [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbup).